# How much extra work to get a glider licence?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, glider

I have my SEL Private VFR licence.  I recently went on a glider flight, and I loved it.  How much extra work does it take a typical pilot to transition from SEL to gliders?

What extra material will I have to learn?  And what overlaps?

Comment: Are you looking from a learning standpoint or about rules and regulations?

Comment: I am asking in terms of regulations.  But from a learning standpoint is something I'm interested in, too.  Can most of the work be done at home?  Or do I need a lot of extra ground school?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(I am assuming your question is asking about the FAA regulations.)

If you already have a PPL, then the requirements are modest. According to the [Soaring Society of America](http://www.ssa.org/GliderPilotRatings):

> **Additional Pilot Rating**
>   Holders of a valid FAA Power plane license with 40 hours as pilot-in-command need a minimum of 10 solo flights to qualify to take the glider flight test. No written exam is required to add a glider rating to a power license. In all cases, refer to the Federal Aviation Regulations for details on pilot licensing.